# How to fix 'TypeError: print() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given' at Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

What should I do?

I put this code into Google Colab

```py
def student(sid, name, age):
    print(sid, name, '(', age, ')')

student(age=23, name=Choe, sid='2016129020')
```

and the Colab says

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-0beaaa7e73eb> in <module>()
      2   print(sid,name,'(',age,')')
      3 
----> 4 student(age=23, name='Choe', sid='2016129020')

<ipython-input-44-0beaaa7e73eb> in student(sid, name, age)
      1 def student(sid, name, age) :
----> 2   print(sid,name,'(',age,')')
      3 
      4 student(age=23, name='Choe', sid='2016129020')

TypeError: print() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given
```

Can't understand. :(
The expected output is : `2016129020 Choe ( 23 )`

Comment: There's likely a different `print` function in scope that takes only 1 positional argument as opposed to the standard built-in print. Can you put a `print(print)` before your own statement and verify that it outputs `<built-in function print>`?

Comment: oh, when I put  print(print), the output is 8

Comment: That is a surprising output, but at least it indicates that it's not the standard print function.

Comment: I don't know anything about Google Colab, but if they're defining an incompatible version of `print`, it doesn't sound promising.

Comment: I lol'd @TomKarzes - I completely agree

Comment: I would try to determine **where** the unexpected print function comes from. If it's from your own code, this is likely reasonably easy to fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm caught off guard

Comment: If you need to temporarily circumvent `print`, you can try `sys.stdout.write`.  Just remember to supply a terminating newline character.

Comment: Oh I solved! I just reset all runtime. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```py
print(' '.join(sid,name,'(',age,')'))
```

`.join()` is a function of any `string`, it will use the `string` to join its arguments to form a single string.

another option is to use the `.format()` function of the string

```py
print('{sid} {name} ( {age} )'.format(sid=sid, name=name, age=age))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code it works without a problem:

```
def student(sid, name, age):
    print(sid, name, '(', age, ')')

student(age=23, name='Choe', sid='2016129020')
# 2016129020 Choe ( 23 )
```

Is it possible that you inadvertently re-defined the built-in print function somewhere? For example, I can reproduce your error like this:

```
def print(x):
    pass # do nothing

def student(sid, name, age):
    print(sid, name, '(', age, ')')

student(age=23, name='Choe', sid='2016129020')
# TypeError: print() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given
```

If that's the case, you should restart your runtime and re-execute your code, being careful not to overwrite built-in functions.